# "Broad host permissions" Warning when publishing extension on Chrome Web Store when there's only 1 link need access

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest

I'm trying to publish an extension on Google Chrome that helps user to check the current Steam server status. I'm using https://crowbar.steamstat.us/gravity.json to help me gather all the server data that I need.

What I have tried in the manifest.json is:

```
    {
      "name": "Steam Status Checker",
      "short_name": "Steam Status",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "This extension gives you the real-time steam status.",
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "https://crowbar.steamstat.us/gravity.json"
          ],
          "js": [
            "content.js"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "https://crowbar.steamstat.us/gravity.json"
      ]
    }
```

However, when I tried to publish this extension, I got this:

> Because of the following issue, your extension may require an in-depth review:
>
> - Broad host permissions
>
> Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the activeTab permission, or specify the sites that your extension needs access to. Both options are more secure than allowing full access to an indeterminate number of sites, and they may help minimize review times.
>
> The activeTab permission allows access to a tab in response to an explicit user gesture.

```
    {
      ...
      "permissions": ["activeTab"]
    }
```

> If your extension only needs to run on certain sites, simply specify those sites in the extension manifest:

```
    {
      ...
      "permissions": ["https://example.com/*"]
    }
```

In my manifest.json, I think I had all these permissions. But why am I getting this error and what should I do to fix it?

Apologize for any bad grammars since I'm not an English speaker.

Comment: Your extension is fine, it doesn't request broad host permissions. The problem is that the web store's detection filters are just that pathetically bad. You can try replying to the message and post in [extension group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions).

Comment: @wOxxOm thx, I'll try it.